# To modify SVG path thickness

Tags: svg

I would like to modify the bootstrap 4 checkbox tick SVG path numbers, but I have no idea how to modify the numbers to achieve this.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 8 8"><path d="M6.564.75l-3.59 3.612-1.538-1.55L0 4.26 2.974 7.25 8 2.193z" fill="red"/></svg>
```

I would like the tick to be a thinner line instead. About the thickness of a CSS border: 2px;

Any SVG experts?

Thanks

Comment: You'd have to redraw it given it's drawn as a fill. Load it into an SVG editor such as Inkscape.

Comment: @RobertLongson I gave it a fill of red, because its white by default.

Comment: @RobertLongson If I put the exact path into inkscape, I can modify it from there?

Answer (score 6):

As a dirty solution you can use `stroke` and `stroke-width` attributes:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 8 8">
    <path stroke="white" stroke-width="1.7px" d="M6.564.75l-3.59 3.612-1.538-1.55L0 4.26 2.974 7.25 8 2.193z" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

**BUT** this will just create a border of a specific color. So you could only use the image on the fitting background.

[image: Before]
[image: After]